# How to add new rows for each id and for each day in month?

Tags: sql, pyspark

Assume I have a pySpark data frame that has only one column which is a set of users id. Let call that data frame be "sid_df". Furthermore, assume the number of users on "sid_df" is 1 million.

Now,  I would like to create a new data frame with 3 three columns. The first column is user id from sid_df, the second column is all days on May, 2018  named "date". The third column is money_earned for that user and for that day on May. Initially I would like the values on third column alls are set to be zeros.

In other words, the new data frame will have 1*31=31 millions records.

Answer (score 0):

Add days 1-31 to a table manually.
For my example the table with numbers is tn

Then use the following query to get the data to insert to your new data frame

```
Select id, tn.number, 0 as amountearned 
from userstable
  Cross join tn
```

Comment: It looks correct and I just found that idea from pyspark library. Thanks for your suggestion again